# Steam won't launch in Ubuntu 18.04 after switching to nvidia graphics

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, graphics, steam

I am a new linux user and just installed Steam on Ubuntu 18. When running in the native graphics card Steam launches both from terminal and from the app icon. When switched to nvidia graphics which has all drivers (supposedly) correctly installed steam won't launch anymore. I tried reinstalling steam and several solutions to similar problems but none worked. How can I solve this?

When I run steam on the terminal the output is:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 18.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Pins up-to-date!
/home/carlosavila/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam
[2019-12-29 14:22:57] Startup - updater built Dec 16 2019 16:48:42
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  48
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
Serial number of failed request:  49
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2019-12-29 14:22:57] Checking for update on startup
[2019-12-29 14:22:57] Checking for available updates...
[2019-12-29 14:22:57] Downloading manifest: client-download.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
[2019-12-29 14:22:58] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1576550254, installed version 1576550254
[2019-12-29 14:22:58] Nothing to do
[2019-12-29 14:22:58] Verifying installation...
[2019-12-29 14:22:58] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2019-12-29 14:22:59] Verification complete
```

And the output to `glxinfo | grep "version"` is:

```
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 390.116
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 390.116
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 390.116
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
    GL_EXT_shader_implicit_conversions, GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix,
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing here is that Nvidia deprecated 32-bits libraries in the `.deb` driver packages and the steam client is a 32-bits binary so it depends on the 32-bits libraries (just to be clear, the problem is not with the driver but with the libraries). There are several ways to fix this, the "theoretically" must recommended solution would be to download the `.run` driver and enable the 32-bits libraries when install, but IMHO install the `.run` is tedious (and I have not done that since several years ago so I really don't know how it will work today).

My empirical-based recommendation is to install the graphics-drivers ppa (https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`, this ppa includes the nvidia drivers and also the 64-bits & 32-bits version of the libraries. It is supposed to be experimental but it really works fine for me.

The only thing you may need to be focus is that once you install the ppa:graphics-drivers, since you already have the nvidia drivers, you will need to "force version" in order to install the ppa:graphics-drivers (even if it is the same nvidia-390 you are already using). I recommend to use the synaptic package manager since you can tell synaptic everything you want to do before applying (since you might want to change several libraries in the process). also in synaptic you may go to the architecture filter and search for `nvidia` filtering to `i386` so you may install every 32-bits nvidia library (which are not going to be installed by default and you need to install them).

Answer (score 0):

This command `__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia steam` works for me. But after restart, it works out of the box.

See my full answer [in other post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1441474/470879)