# After installing NVIDIA drivers i can't launch games on Steam

Tags: nvidia, amd-graphics, hybrid-graphics, amd-ryzen

I have an ASUS laptop with AMD Ryzen 7 4800h  and NVIDIA 1660 Ti. I am trying to play Satisfactory on Steam. It works with iGPU. However, after installing the latest NVIDIA driver from Software & Updates the game doesn't launch and shows a black screen with an error message.

[image: Software & Updates - Additional Drivers]

[image: Steam error]

Here is the output of `journalctl -xe`: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/CssswJs2Xf/

I've tried all the drivers on the list, but none of them worked (except for Nouveau, which was automatically selected).

Comment: could you post the result of `journalctl -xe` in your answer? (Only the part when you try to start the game) Which NVIDIA version did you install?

Comment: I shared output and screenshots now. Also, if xorg driver is selected, the game launches but fps is very low.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue on Fedora 37. But I hope the solution works for Ubuntu too.

The game I played (Battle Realms: Zen Edition) works with Noveau + Wayland. But After I installed nvidia driver using [this step](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/fedora-37-nvidia-kernel-module-missing-falling-back-to-nouveau/27033/6) which works for all non-steam game. The "Battle Realms: Zen Edition" refuses to start from Steam app.

This command `__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia steam` works for me. But after restart, it works out of the box.

Credit:

- [Gaming on Fedora + NVIDIA = Not Working - Ask Fedora](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/gaming-on-fedora-nvidia-not-working/8280/17)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a wireless problem:

> Şub 02 16:36:33 asus kernel: purge skb(s) not reported by firmware
> Şub 02 16:36:33 asus kernel: WARNING: CPU: 9 PID: 0 at drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtw88/tx.c:159 rtw_tx_report_purge_timer+0x25/0x60 [rtw88_core]

This seems to be covered [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1890096), but will probably not be the reason for your game not to play.

Since it generates kernel dumps you should get the correct drivers for them

**EDIT**
Steam describes the problem [here](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6316-GJKC-7437&l=english) using the "primus" 32 bit library. That explains why it runs on you internal GPU but not on NVIDIA